# Android 4.0.3 - Web Services updates not working properly

Tags: android, cordova, android-firmware

I have created an app using phonegap, which uses web services to update the html pages, images etc. This worked perfectly on my Samsung Galaxy S2 using 2.35, however as soon as I upgraded the firmware to 4.0.3 this update stopped working properly.

It seems to be mainly the image update which is not working properly, does anybody know of any such issue and if so are there any hacks/ work arounds.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that this was due to updates done by Google on their firmware. They are dilebretly tying to put minimum effort into allowing full functionality to Web Apps, due to the fact that they gernally only want native apps on the market. A prime example of these issues is something as simple as links do not work properly:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535

Although, my understanding is that for the major issue, they are working on fixes.